# OAuth2.0 to vk.com using curl in bash

Tags: bash, curl, oauth-2.0, vk

I want to write a bash script which will work with vk.com API.

My first step is to make OAuth2.0 authorization. But i can't use web browser because my script will work on machine without xserver.

As described on developers page i need firstly to make GET request:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=<myapp_id>&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=mobile&scope=video,audio&response_type=token&v=5.44&revoke=1
```

With this request is everything OK. Then i opened source code of this page and found there next code:

```
<form method="post" action="https://login.vk.com/?act=login&soft=1&utf8=1">
<input type="hidden" name="_origin" value="https://oauth.vk.com">
<input type="hidden" name="ip_h" value="<some_value>" />
<input type="hidden" name="lg_h" value="<some_value>" />
<input type="hidden" name="to" value="<some_value>">
<dl class="fi_row">
<dt class="fi_label">Phone or email:</dt>
<dd>
<div class="iwrap"><input type="text" class="textfield" name="email" value="" /></div>
</dd>
</dl>
<dl class="fi_row">
<dt class="fi_label">Password:</dt>
<dd>
<div class="iwrap"><input type="password" class="textfield" name="pass" /></div>
</dd>
</dl>
<div class="fi_row">
<div class="fi_subrow">
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Log in" /><div class="near_btn"><a href="//oauth.vk.com/blank.html#error=access_denied&error_reason=user_denied&error_description=User denied your request">Cancel</a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="fi_row_new">
<div class="fi_header fi_header_light">Not registered yet?</div>
</div>
<div class="fi_row">
<a class="button wide_button gray_button" href="https://m.vk.com/join?api_hash=a9612b3095c82d30df">Sign up for VK</a>
</div>
</form>
```

It means that to make authorization i need to send POST request to

```
https://login.vk.com/?act=login&soft=1&utf8=1
```

and pass as parameters next inputs:

```
_origin, ip_h, lg_h, to, email, pass
```

but it's not working. I'm getting nothing using curl and getting error page with message about incorrect pass or login using different rest clients using gui. I thought that problem may be in cookies but adding cookies give nothing.

script code i am trying to make work:

```
#!/bin/bash
username=$1
password=$2

response=$(curl --cookie-jar vk.txt "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize" --data "client_id=<app_id>&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=mobile&scope=video,audio&response_type=token&v=5.44&revoke=1")
echo "response is $response"
echo "================================================================="
response=$(curl --request POST --cookie vk.txt "https://login.vk.com/?act=login&soft=1&utf8=1" --data-urlencode "_origin=https://oauth.vk.com&ip_h=<some_value>&lg_h=<some_value>&to=<some_value>&email=<my_email>&pass=<my_pass>")
echo "response is $response"
echo "================================================================="

exit 0
```

I'he tried different params in curl, different cookie formats. But result the same.
Maybe the problem that i need to do special security encodes because of SSL? But shouldn't curl do it?

I found out one script on python where author didn't do any more actions when i, but his code works fine. Of course it's may be because of his third party libs for rest requests but maybe not. Link to this paper (in Russian):
https://habrahabr.ru/post/143972/

Comment: What's the question here exactly?

Comment: after my second request i should get page with permissions but i am not getting this page. i'm getting error page using rest client and getting nothing (maybe blank page) using curl. The question is what i'm doing wrong?